# Suspecting slow DNS, without possibility to change it

Tags: dns, performance

Recently my ISP fixed primary and secondary DNS server addresses in my device. No explanation why, they just confirmed it's now what it is and can't be changed anymore.

Around the same time I started noticing that when I visit a website, sometimes it takes 3-5 seconds before anything is shown in the browser, and even then (in case of YouTube for example) it takes additional few seconds to load thumbnails.
My overall connection is good, 200/50 mbps with minimums around 60/20 but subjective feeling is horrible.

In order to check what's going on I tried running traceroute command (I'm using Linux) and found out that when I do traceroute against URL it usually takes about 5 seconds before any result is printed and then entire traceroute result is printed without delay.
When I do traceroute against IP address, results are printed immediately without initial delay.

This is a print of my traceroute command I executed just now. In this case after "1", "4" and "9" I had delays of about few seconds each:

```
> traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (142.250.180.238), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (192.168.0.1)  1.084 ms  1.044 ms  1.025 ms
 2  100.64.0.1 (100.64.0.1)  9.758 ms  9.738 ms  9.721 ms
 3  172.31.255.2 (172.31.255.2)  15.516 ms  15.498 ms  15.804 ms
 4  172.31.255.2 (172.31.255.2)  14.995 ms  14.976 ms  14.959 ms
 5  bg-ne-m-0-be4-100.sbb.rs (89.216.12.16)  16.550 ms  16.052 ms  16.515 ms
 6  bg-tp-m-0-hg7-2.sbb.rs (89.216.5.248)  16.523 ms  15.398 ms  15.368 ms
 7  72.14.219.230 (72.14.219.230)  19.702 ms  14.654 ms  14.547 ms
 8  * * *
 9  172.253.65.38 (172.253.65.38)  20.011 ms 142.251.65.222 (142.251.65.222)  24.502 ms 142.251.65.220 (142.251.65.220)  25.914 ms
10  142.251.65.219 (142.251.65.219)  24.321 ms  24.262 ms  24.197 ms
11  bud02s34-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.180.238)  24.246 ms  24.179 ms  24.122 ms
```

Does it sound like a DNS problem?

If it's a DNS issue, do you think I can solve it by attaching a simple modem to my ISP device, set DNS address of my desire in settings of that modem and connect my laptop to that modem instead of directly onto ISP device (Ubee EVW32C)?

If it's not a DNS issue, what it might be?

I'm connected via 2.4 Ghz WiFi. ISP device is in adjacent room (2 meters away, thin wall). Same results i get if i connect via 5Ghz. Haven't tried LAN connection, I don't have a LAN cable at the moment.

Comment: Why do you believe it's impossible to change the DNS configuration of your device? If your ISP provided DNS is slow, the only way to resolve that problem, is to change the your DNS configuration.

Comment: Nope, as soon as i change it device restarts with ISP defaults and they directly told me "yup, we are now enforcing said address"....

Comment: I understand your ISP managing your Ubee EVW32C but what about your client devices?

Comment: Well that's the question - if the problem seems to be DNS, can i avoid it by connecting my own router to ISP device and THERE set my DNS addresses? :)

Comment: As @Ramhound states, unless you let you ISP have physical access to your PC, you can change the DNS resolution settings. See https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using for example.

Comment: Yes; Have you tested it with one of your client devices running Linux?

Comment: drmoishe-pippik hmmm i wouldn't change my lapptop config just because of that :) I would prefer (if possible) using another man-in-the-middle device in order to have the same setting on phones too. Ramhound - nope, I haven't tried with my own router, wasn't sure if it would even work :)

Comment: Also, potentially using in-the-middle device would allow me to setup something like PiHole if/when needed ;)

Comment: For yest purposes though, commenting out a line in /etc/resolv.conf and adding alternative with a different nameserver should nit be a big deal to confirm/eliminate the DNS theory (which sounds likely) - and is trivial to revert - and likely temporary anyway.

Comment: Also, can you advise what country you are in?  Its possible your issues tie in with Internet sensorship.

Comment: @davidgo hmmm putting 8.8.8.8 in resolv.conf gave no difference at least in respect to traceroute. Opening websites - i'mmm not so sure. I'm in Serbia, there's no internet censorship of any kind here